# After Magento upgrade from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.3

i have upgrade my magento version from 2.2.8 to **2.3.3** after upgrade when i run setup upgrade command i am getting this error in ebizmart mail chimp extension

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Ebizmarts\MailChimp\Helper\Data::encrypt()

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your **Ebizmart module** for now, after upgrade again install this Module with upgraded libraries.

Process to Install are : (with composer)

1. Run this command on Magento's root dir:

   composer config repositories.ebizmarts composer https://packages.ebizmarts.com
2. Run this command on Magento's root dir. Contact us to get your access token.

   composer config http-basic.gitlab.ebizmarts.com token your_token
3. Run this command to get the module.

   composer require ebizmarts/mailChimp
4. Run this command to install the module
           bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: How to set theme after migration?

Comment: no need to set theme, you need to basic integrate in magento2 to no sample data instance.

Answer (score 0):

The repos in https://packages.ebizmarts.com are private and you can't access if you don't have an user/pass (and you must pay for that)

As you know, mc-magento2 is a free extension and you can install it simply with composer (with no other unnecessary trick), and mc-magento2 is not in these repos!!

The problem here is, the version of mc-magento2 for magento 2.2.8 don't work in magento 2.3.3, so you must follow these steps

1. Prior to update your magento, uninstall mc-magento2 (run composer remove mailchimp/mc-magento2)
2. Once the extension is uninstalled, update your magento installation
3. When you finished the update, simply run composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:102.3.37 (for know what version you must install visit https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases and search for the version that fit your magento version)

That's all

Answer (score 0):

We have issue with ebizmarts MC for magneto 2.3. we recently upgraded from 2.2.7 to 2.3.3. after that email are not sent and Cron jobs get sql error. Currently version of MC is 1.0.28, is this wrong? Should I install MC V102.3.37?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove module **Ebizmarts\MailChimp** and re-setup the version